# Minimal, uniquely ergodic but not Lebesgue-ergodic?

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory

So here's my question:

Does there exist a minimal diffeomorphism of class at least $\mathcal{C^2}$ of a compact manifold X which is

1. minimal
2. uniquely ergodic with unique probability measure $\mu$
3. not ergodic with respect to the Lebesgue measure ?

I don't really see why these requirements should contradict each other but I haven't been able to find an example. Note that the regularity hypothesis is necessary as (see R.W.'s answer below): there are $\mathcal{C}^1$ circle diffeomorphisms that satisfy those conditions, but one could argue that they are a bit artificial since as soon as the derivative is required to have bounded variation this can no longer be true.

I would also be happy with any example that is just a piecewise diffeomorphism!

Comment: Just take something like a shift on the circle, but use non-standard coordinates so that Lebesgue measure becomes something else in the new coordinates. (More to the point perhaps, what is "Lebesgue measure" anyway on a manifold?)

Comment: Hi Christian. If you use "non-standard coordinates", then you loose the fact that your map is a diffeo. For any smooth manifold, the class of the Lebesgue measure is well-defined and it makes sense to say that a diffeo is ergodic (when the measure of any invariant set or its complement is zero for any representative of the class). It is standard that any sufficiently regular ($\mathcal{C}^2$) minimal circle diffeo is ergodic with respect to Lebesgue.

Comment: By "non-standard coordinates," I meant a smooth change of variable, so the map stays $C^{\infty}$.

Comment: In that case you won’t be able to produce any example.

Comment: So you mean you want the ergodic measure to have a singular component? You didn't say this though.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: If you do a smooth change of coordinates, then the Lebesgue measure is (of course) mapped to something mutually absolutely continuous with respect to Lebesgue. This measure remains ergodic (even though it is not invariant): for any invariant set $A$, if you pull it back by the change of coordinates has measure 0 or 1, and so $A$ itself has 0 or 1 with respect to Lebesgue.

Comment: @ChristianRemling I am making no assumption on the ergodic measure. It seems to me that the question makes sense formulated as it is...

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Yes, of course I know all that. The OP asked (item 3) for an invariant measure that is not Lebesgue measure, and my trivial example does that. (It now turns out the OP really meant: the ergodic measure is not *equivalent* to Lebesgue measure.)

Comment: @ChristianRemling No I didn't meant that. Although item 2 and 3 together imply that the invariant measure is not equivalent to Lebesgue, 3. demands that Lebesgue is not ergodic which is much stronger.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: Actually, I have no idea what the second part of your comment is about. The transformed measure is invariant because it's the same as before, just expressed in the new coordinates, and, in general, ergodic measures are invariant as part of the definition (at least for me).

Comment: So the definition of ergodic as I understand the OP is $T^{-1}A=A$ implies $\lambda(A)=A$. This makes sense for non-invariant measures. If one starts with a circle rotation and conjugated by something smooth, the new map preserves the push-forward of the original measure (which will generally not be Lebesgue). Nonetheless, Lebesgue measure is ergodic for the new map according to the definition that the OP is using.

Comment: @AnthonyQuas: That (this non-standard definition of "ergodic") may have been the OP's intention, but it seems a bad idea: for example, then any measure $\delta_x$ is "ergodic," so how could a system ever be uniquely "ergodic" ? It really would have been better to use the standard definitions and say clearly and explicitly what is meant.

Comment: @ChristianRemling: this is actually a standard definition in non-singular ergodic theory, although I agree the juxtaposition of this terminology with the term uniquely ergodic is quite unfortunate.

Comment: @Christian Remling As Anthony says, the definitions used by the OP are absolutely standard and the question is completely clear. The notion of ergodicity is routinely defined and used for quasi-invariant measures (and their classes) as well, and OP tacitly referred to the fact that the Lebesgue measure **class** (one shouldn't really talk about **the** Lebesgue measure on a smooth manifold) is quasi-invariant with respect to any diffeomorphism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't manage to find an online version, but [this paper](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet/search/publdoc.html?arg3=&co4=AND&co5=AND&co6=AND&co7=AND&dr=all&pg4=AUCN&pg5=TI&pg6=PC&pg7=ALLF&pg8=ET&r=1&review_format=html&s4=yoccoz&s5=denjoy-koksma&s6=&s7=&s8=All&sort=Newest&vfpref=html&yearRangeFirst=&yearRangeSecond=&yrop=eq) by Yoccoz provides an example of a diffeomorphism of the $2$-dimensional torus which is the product of two analytic circle diffeomorphisms, which is minimal, uniquely ergodic, and totally dissipative for Lebesgue measure (hence it cannot be ergodic).

Comment: Hi Andres, thank you for your answer. I have just read the abstract on Math Sci Net and it certainly answers the question. If anyone knows where to find the text I'd be super grateful...

Answer (score 5):

You haven't specified the smoothness, so that hopefully $C^1$ is OK. It was Denjoy who proved in 1932 that if a $C^1$ diffeomorphism $f$ of the circle has an irrational rotation number $\alpha$ and its derivative has bounded variation, then it is $C^0$-conjugate to the $\alpha$-rotation, and therefore is uniquely ergodic. Answering Denjoy's question, [Herman (1979)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=538680) and Katok (see Section 3.6 of [Cornfeld-Fomin-Sinai](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=832433)) proved that if $f$ is $C^2$ and an irrational rotation number, then it is also ergodic with respect to the Lebesgue measure. Later the $C^2$ condition was replaced by [Katok-Hasselblatt](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1326374) with Denjoy's condition ($C^1$ and bounded variation of the derivative).

[Oliveira and da Rocha (2001)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1869073) gave an example of a minimal non-ergodic (with respect to the Lebesgue measure) $C^1$ diffeomorphism $f$ of the circle which is $C^0$ conjugate to an irrational rotation (and therefore is uniquely ergodic). Finally, [Kodama and Matsumoto (2013)](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3034431) showed that non-ergodicity in such examples can be made "the strongest possible", namely $f$ can be chosen to be completely dissipative with respect to the Lebesgue measure, i.e., such that its ergodic components are just orbits, or, equivalently, it admits a measurable "fundamental domain".

Comment: Hi RW, thank you for your answer. Actually what I had in mind was the problem in high regularity as I was aware of those examples (sorry for not being precise enough in my question). What actually initiated my interest in this question is the following problem: can you find minimal, uniquely ergodic $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ interval exchange transformations that are not Lebesgue ergodic? which would be the natural generalisation of the Herman-Katok result you are referring to...

Comment: What do you mean by $C^\infty$ interval exchange transformations?

Comment: A piecewise continuous bijection of the interval with finitely many discontinuity points which $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ where it is continuous. It is sometimes called 'generalised' interval exchange transformation.

Comment: Is this the same as a usual exchange transformation combined with a $C^\infty$ time change?

Comment: By global time change do you mean conjugated to via a $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$? Because if it is the case the answer to your question is no. It is formally what I have said in my previous comment (see https://arxiv.org/pdf/1003.1191.pdf for precise definitions). I think a good way to say it is that $\mathcal{C}^{\infty}$ interval exchange transformation are to standard interval exchange transformations what circle diffeos are to rotations.

Comment: OK, I see - I didn't say "global" though :))